# Raspberry pi to reset my server

Tags: linux, server, reset, gpio, reboot

Problem:
My home server have a tendency to freeze up every now and then. This seems to be random and i can't figure out why it does it. When this happens i have to reboot it, and it works fine again. Typically this happens once a week or so. I am not home a lot, and therefore it's a problem if this happens when i'm gone, because i can't physically hit the reset button to restart the server. When it has frozen i can't ssh to the box or in any way acces it remotely.

Possible solution.
I was thinking i could connect a raspberry pi to my servers motherboard's reset pins and have the raspberry pi ping the server once in a while, and if it gets no response, then close the circuit to the reset pin and thereby rebooting the server. This eliminates the need for me to wait until i will be back home to do this manually. Alternatively i have been thinking of setting up an ssh access to the pi, so i could run the script to reset from there.

Is this at all feasable and if so, can you point me in the right direction, so i can do some research on this.

Any other suggestions to reboot my server remotely when it's frozen will also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This reminds me of [an  old story on the DailyWTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/articles/ITAPPMONROBOT). It sounds both feasible, and fun to try.

Comment: look for a "watchdog" in the server BIOS. Sounds like this is the exact scenario they are made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the basic idea already.

If you look inside the casing of your server, you should find the wires running from your power/reset button to the pins on the motherboard. Typically pressing the reset button shorts two pins together.

Seeing as the PI's GPIO pins run on 3.3 volts, it is likely safer to go with the opting of using a basic NPN transistor driven by the PI to mimic the pushing of the reset button on your server. You would splice into each one of the wires, connecting one end to the collector, and one end to the emitter. You'd connect a pin on your PI to the base through a resistor. At that point you'd need to write your program to drive the pin that is connected to the transistor high when you wanted to reset your server.

There are a number of tutorials online detailing how to operate the GPIO pins through a programming language of your choice.

The resistor and transistor needed should only cost about $0.50-$1.00 at a local electronics shop or online. A 2N3904 transistor and a 175 Ohm resistor should work just fine.

Comment: This looks very interesting! I have found the transistor i need without a problem. However the resistor seems a little harder since this is my first experience with this kind of technology. I can't find one that specifies 175 ohm. Can you send me a product number like the transistor to one that would work?

Comment: Transistors are so simple, I wouldn't be concerned with finding an exact one. Any 1/4 watt resistor that is roughly 175 ohms will do just fine. 180 ohms is a standard value, I'd go for that.

Comment: Thanks. So this would be good enough? https://www.elextra.dk/main.aspx?page=article&artno=H12934

Comment: Yup, looks good to me. Of course, I would recommend you trying your setup with an LED before hooking it up to your server, better safe than sorry. With an LED, you will likely another 180 ohm resistor inline with it. Put the second resistor at the emitter, and your LED after that. This will demonstrate that your transistor is working as intended before moving forward.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This was just what i needed. Hopefully this will solve my problem.